# Exclude a directory from mod_qos

Tags: php, download

Is possible to exclude a directory from mod_qos filtering?

I have a php download script that finishes the download of a file with 20MB on 4Mb, the mod_qos is blocking the download with this error message:

[error] mod_qos(034): access denied, QS_SrvMinDataRate rule (**out**): min=150, this connection=0, c=

Or is possible to use the mod_rewrite to exclude the directoru /downloads ? For example execute the mod_qos rules only if the URI is not /downloads ?

PHP code:

```html
$filename = 'test.exe';
$filepath = "downloads/";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
set_time_limit(0);
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($filepath.$filename);
```